# Instantiate a new Howler Object in Action Creators and dispatch actions on events

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, action, howler.js

So I'm trying to build a React.js + Redux audio player.
I'm using the Howler.js Library to process audio from an API.
I'm dispatching actions from the player control buttons and from other component such as a track list component. 
When the user clicks on a track in the lis, I'm dispatching a track object to the Player Reducer. I instantiate a new Howl Object here which works **but there is some issues here :**

- Because Howler is fetching the data from an API, this is an async task and it's an anti pattern. I know that, but here I'm not triggering events from Howler so it works, but it's a bit buggy.
- I can't use event triggers because it would be async and it's a bad pratice to dispatch actions from the Reducer.

**What I would like :**

- Instanciate a new Howler Object in my Action Creator.
- Use the event triggers, e.g : onload() or onloaderror(), to dispatch an other action to tell the player that Howler is ready to play a song or if there was an error.

**The code :**

Action Creator

```
export const PLAYER_INITIALIZE = 'PLAYER_INITIALIZE'
export const initialize = () => {
    return {
        type: PLAYER_INITIALIZE,
    }
}

export const PLAYER_SET_TRACK = 'PLAYER_SET_TRACK'
export const setTrack = (trackId) => {
    return {
        type: PLAYER_SET_TRACK,
    }
}

export const PLAYER_PLAY_TRACK = 'PLAYER_PLAY_TRACK'
export const playTrack = () => {
    return {
        type: PLAYER_PLAY_TRACK,
    }
}
```

Reducer

```
function PlayerReducer(state = initialPlayerState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {

        case PlayerActions.PLAYER_SET_TRACK:
            if (state.audioObj.state() != 'unloaded')
                state.audioObj.unload();
            return {
                ...state,
                audioObj: new Howl({
                    src: API.API_STREAM_TRACK + action.trackId,
                    html5: true,
                    preload: true,
                    onload: () => {
                        console.log("Track loaded succesfully.");
                    },
                    onloaderror: (id, err) => {
                        console.error("Load Error : " + err);
                    }
                }),
                trackMetadata: action.trackMetadata
            };

        case PlayerActions.PLAYER_PLAY_TRACK:
            state.audioObj.play();
            return {
                ...state,
                isPlaying: true,
            };

      [...]
```

***My idea is to instanciate Howler like this :***

```
new Howler({
    [ ... some options ],
    onload: () => {
        dispatch({
            type: PLAYER_LOAD_SUCCESS
        });
    },
    onloaderror: () => {
        dispatch({
            type: PLAYER_LOAD_ERROR
        });
    }
});
```

How can I edit this code to create a new Howl Object correctly in the Action Creator and pass it to the player on each track that I want to listen?

Can you give me an example ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) to your app and then be able to dispatch multiple actions from a single action creator. After adding redux-thunk, your action could look like the following:

```js
export const setTrack = (trackId) => {
  (dispatch, getState) => {
    const { audioObj } = getState();
    if (audioObj != null) {
      audioObj.unload();
    }

    dispatch({
      audioObj:  new Howler({
          [ ... some options ],
          onload: () => {
              dispatch({
                  type: PLAYER_LOAD_SUCCESS
              });
          },
          onloaderror: () => {
              dispatch({
                  type: PLAYER_LOAD_ERROR
              });
          }
      }),
      type: PLAYER_SET_TRACK
  });
}
```

you can move your other async and Howler work into action creators this way and make your reducer only concerned with storing information.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But How do I call async functions from components? Do I need to do : `dispatch(setTrack(theTrack))` ?

Comment: The function is synchronous,  it's called like a normal action creator. `dispatch(setTrack(trackId));`.